# Tracing an S-shaped logo in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've been trying to trace this image without any success. I just can't seem to get the shapes right, I've tried to use a grid while tracing to ensure that I get the right thickness, but nothing seems to give me the result I need.

How would you trace a logo like this? What technique am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would start by drawing circles and ovals then because it has symmetry i would build it out of those circles by offsetting the other edge and finally building it out with tweaks. Manually tracing the image is in this case the sanest solution. The logo is quite simple to decostruct.

[image: built out of shapes]

**Image 1**: Build out of simple shapes and offset

Once i have the symmetry and offset aligned I build and merge the shapes and offset for the other edge. And then tweak

[image: this is what i end up with]

**Image 2**: and what I end up with after 10 minutes of work

**Edit**: since i get both sides of the curve with the offset. i can just turn it into a single stroke by averaging the vertices and control points between the 2 curves (using blend).

[image: average]

**Image 3**: you can get the average with the blend tool

You can then use a stroke to guesstimate the shape.

[image: Stroke]

**Image 4**: Using central stroke

Comment: Nice, but that ain't tracing, it's reproducing.

Comment: @Vincent You can not allays get what you want. Its still a manual trace with guides. So i would do this manually.

Answer (score 4):

here is my solution

1. first you have to correct the image for making it easier to illustrator to trace the artwork. open photoshop and adjust the level contract as follow.

[image]

2. now open the artwork in illustrator or drag and drop it or just place it by `file>place...` command and trace it using the following settings.

[image]

3. after tracing the image expand it then right click on the result traced image and `ungroup` and then 'release clipping mask', now you should see your layers as follow

[image]

delete the white layer and just keep three layer, one is the circle and two for the paths. you should delete one of the paths for identically duplicate it. recolor it to white.

4. now it is the step where you delete and adjust the anchor points for smoother result.

[image][image] [image]
select the two anchor points and align them to bottom.

5. Now retrieve the center point of the circle by dragging a horizontal and vertical guide lines to determine the center point where the shape will rotate.

[image]

6. select the rotate tool and alt click over the intersection of the guidelines. a dialogue box will appear and set the rotation value to 180 and click over the copy button.

[image]

7. that's it. .. for best result you should draw a newer circle from the intersected guidelines, as the traced circle most probably is not a perfect circle.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is easier to re-create than to trace.Half a circle plus a two point line and some width tool (Shift+W) adjustment. Then mirror it (twice).

Quick and dirty:

[image]

Comment: this is a good job ... however it is not an answer for his question. he/she ask: "How would you guys do it when tracing a logo like this? What technique am I missing? "

Comment: True, but what he might be missing is that it can more easily be reproduced than traced. The choice of tool or technique should never be dictated.